# Is there any way to switch to scene mode from game mode when pressing the play button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically my question: Is there any way to switch from scene mode to gamemode script wise?
Image of what I want to do but from script

[image]

I am basically asking because I  want to take a screenshot of the assets I load into the scene.
My code:

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("HELLO");
        var rss = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(@"//MyFileLocation");
        Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        foreach (var asset in rss.LoadAllAssets<GameObject>())//<Texture2D>())
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(asset, transform);
        }
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
        Application.CaptureScreenshot(@"//MyScreenshotlocation");
        Debug.Log("captured");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }   
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to any Window with the `EditorWindow.FocusWindowIfItsOpen` function. To switch to Scene view, pass `SceneView` to it. You can use `EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged` to determine when you enter play mode.

This is an Editor plugin and must be placed in a folder named "Editor". Create a script called `SceneSwitcher` and copy everything below inside it. It should automatically switch to Scene View when you click the play button.

```
using UnityEditor;

[InitializeOnLoadAttribute]
public static class SceneSwitcher
{
    static SceneSwitcher()
    {
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += LogPlayModeState;
    }

    private static void LogPlayModeState(PlayModeStateChange state)
    {
        if (state == PlayModeStateChange.EnteredPlayMode)
            SwitchToSceneView();
    }

    static void SwitchToSceneView()
    {
        EditorWindow.FocusWindowIfItsOpen<SceneView>();

        /////OR
        //SceneView sceneView = EditorWindow.GetWindow<SceneView>(); ;
        //Type type = sceneView.GetType();
        //EditorWindow.FocusWindowIfItsOpen(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: \*Rubs chin\* So in theory I could write an editor script that would switch to the scene tab when I press a certain key? Neat. Always wanted to do that.

Comment: Yup. Sometimes it is needed since Unity automatically switches to GameView

Comment: @Programmer I've tried to add that to my main script class (NewBehaviourScript) but seems like when I add your code the CaptureScreenshot is not saving the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Read the instruction again in the answer instead of jumping into the code. It says: 1.Create a script named `SceneSwitcher`. 2.Put in in a folder named "Editor". That's it. You **cannot** attach it to a GameObject. It's an Editor script that will just work when placed in your project. No MonoBehaviour necessary or required.